# Saving composer dependencies to GIT or not

Tags: php, git, zend-framework2, composer-php

I'm wondering wether to add my (ZF2) dependencies, installed by composer, to my GIT repository or not. This is a discussion I'm heaving with a colleague, how to deal with the vendor directory. I know it is discouraged to add the vendor to my VCS, and to only commit composer.json and composer.lock, but I don't completely understand why this is. This would mean I would have to install dependencies on the production environment using composer aswell.

Isn't it a bit dangerous to rely on external sources for a production environment? Seems to me it's safer to just add all the dependencies to my VCS, update them when needed on the development environment and when all is working find push the update to the VCS aswell. It means we need a bit more diskspace of-course, but I don't think that should be a reason to choose a less safe solution.

Can anybody explain why it's better to let composer deal with the dependencies on a long term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked with both setups.

Keeping all the dependencies in the VCS adds some noise to git history, and gives no advantages.

`composer install` is safe enough, as it fetches exact versions, and does it once during deployment. If it fails by any reason, it just fail the build, and may indicate major problems, e.g. with network.

If you fear that external repositories are unavailable during the build, you can always use [satis](https://github.com/composer/satis) to make 'local' copy of required 3rd-party repositories.

It is also quite common to add composer hooks as part of the building process. Without composer you will need to do it yourself.

The biggest advantage of using composer though, is to prevent 'quick fixes' in 3rd party libraries without proper forking.

Comment: My point with safety is more about what happends if the server the projects runs on dies over a couple of years and I need deploy a new version of the application. If one of the packages is removed the application can't run anymore because you miss a dependency. And the quickfixes still won't happen as you still use composer to update packages, just the way they are stored is different.

Comment: You will wonder how often people leave debugging `var_dump`s  in 3rd party libraries. Do you run `composer update` often? I don't think so.

Comment: Saying about removed projects, doesn't satis resolve this issue?

Comment: No I don't run composer update often indeed. But if I run it, I run it on a development environment first so I can check if everything works correctly. If it gives a var_dump somewhere, I don't commit it to my own repository ;) And satis can be a solution indeed, I'm looking into it. Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: Bless you, sir. I'd wish I was so mindful and never push silly mistakes to origin. I have some excuses like  `vendor` is  not covered with unittests, and it is not always easy to spot your typo in a commit when you have a huge diff of 3rd-party updates. The truth is, chances to break something accidentally are much higher, comparing with recommended approach.

Comment: As mentioned Satis is a good option, you can have it download your package dependencies and maintain a local mirror -> https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md#resolving-dependencies

Comment: @Alex Blex How about unmerged conflicts! views_rss_itunes drupal module is a perfect example of this... They force-checked it right in

Answer (score 3):

The official recommendation is to [commit your `.composer.json` and `composer.lock`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file) but [not your vendor directory](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md):

> ### Should I commit the dependencies in my vendor directory?
>
> The general recommendation is **no**. The vendor directory (or wherever your dependencies are installed) should be added to `.gitignore`/`svn:ignore`/etc.
>
> The best practice is to then have all the developers use Composer to install the dependencies. Similarly, the build server, CI, deployment tools etc should be adapted to run Composer as part of their project bootstrapping.
>
> While it can be tempting to commit it in some environment, it leads to a few problems:
>
> - Large VCS repository size and diffs when you update code.
> - Duplication of the history of all your dependencies in your own VCS.
> - Adding dependencies installed via git to a git repo will show them as submodules. This is problematic because they are not real submodules, and you will run into issues.

That same page lists some best practices if you still want to commit your vendor directory.

Comment: Thank you. I did read this page, but it doesn't answer the question what happens if one of the dependencies is removed and you need a completely new copy of the application.

Comment: If you are using dependencies whose future is unstable enough that you think they could be removed without warning, you should fork them.

Comment: @TimFountain, you may miss some nested dependencies tho. I can hardly predict what eventually appear in the `lock` file for a given `composer.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the diffs every time you update dependencies.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Yes there will be a difference when I update the dependencies, but then I just commit the updates to the VCS aswell.

Comment: By diffs I mean VCS history.